# How to save value of binary field from odoo-11 to the desired location on my computer?

Tags: python, python-3.6, odoo, odoo-11

I have stored pdf file into the binary filed in odoo-11, now I want to store that pdf file on my desktop. So how can I archive it in odoo-11 ?

Comment: Please show us what you've worked on so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :- below is the code to store binary file from odoo field to your file system

```
with open(os.path.join('path_where_file_will_be_downloaded', 'filename.extension'), "wb+") as f:
    f.write(name_of_binary_field)
```